# Embedding a matplotlib chart into Qt/C++ application

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, python-embedding

I am developing an math-oriented GUI application in Qt/C++ and would like to embed a Python scripting, including NumPy and Matplotlib. Using Python C API, I finally managed to run a script, retrieve the values from the Python variables, including NumPy arrays etc. But I failed at drawing Matplotlib charts into my Qt/C++ application.

It is better to say, I have managed to save the chart's RGBA buffer to a variable using Python script, then get the value of the variable as a PyObject of buffer type, get the buffer and transform it to QImage then to QPixmap and finally put it into QLabel and display it.

But I am still missing its interactive behaviour, resizing etc. though it seems that it can be done by forwarding Qt mouse events to figure.canvas.button_press_event but it is then getting overly complicated... So I concluded I do not understand the principles of Python embedding well enough. I am missing something obvious.

I found some samples of embedding matplotlib charts into PyQt or PySide (i.e. written in Python) applications where I have seen something like QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(canvas) or layout.addWidget(canvas). Here canvas is FigureCanvasQTAgg object ( http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_qt4agg_api.html ).

This suggests that canvas inherits from QWidget. But when I try mimic this in C++ code using Python's C API, I end with just a PyObject *canvas, not knowing how to trasform it to a QWidget. This is my snippet without the important step:

```
//draw a figure in Python script called from C++ app
PyRun_SimpleString("import matplotlib\n"
"matplotlib.use('Qt4agg')\n" //use Qt4 backend
"import pylab\n"
"pylab.plot(randn(10))\n" //plot something
"fig = pylab.gcf()\n" //take current figure
"canvas = fig.canvas" //canvas is of FigureCanvasQTAgg type

//get canvas as PyObject
PyObject* m = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* canvas = PyObject_GetAttrString(m, "canvas");
//from what I know, canvas is a PyObject wrapped around an object derived from QWidget

//...
//... here I do not know how to convert canvas (i.e. PyObject) into canvasWidget (i.e. QWidget)???
//... 

//show chart as a widget
MyWindow.setCentralWidget(canvasWidget)
```

As I wrote, I must be missing something obvious. I googled everywhere but without success. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: This is a curious question, you want to wrap in c++ the python wrapper of a c++ class ;)  You are correct that `FigureCanvasQTAgg` _is_ a `QWidget` object,  but I also don't know enough about embedding to get a reference to the underlying QT object out.

Comment: tcaswell - Yes, this is exactly what I would need - extract the reference or pointer or whatever QWidget from PyObject.

Comment: My only suggestion is to look into exactly what `PyQt` or `PySide` are doing underneath.

Comment: Does the posted answer solve your problem?

Comment: I am sorry, for not replying sooner and thank you for your patience. I will check the suggested solution. However I decided othewise and chose the safest way, and reworked my entire app into pure Python+PyQt application which might have some performance drawbacks compared to Qt/C++ but so far it seems satisfactory. Anyway, out of curiosity I will test what you and bks suggested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this question should receive more attention, as an inceasing number of developers (including myself) find it interesting to interface `Matplotlib` with a C++ application, which stands for a better plotting solution than `qwt` or other libraries with under-average rendering capabilities and limited plotting API. For interested people, check this [Github project](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PySide, I suggest reading [this comp.lib.qt.pyside thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.pyside/3819) and also the section on [type converters](https://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/typeconverters.html) in the PySide docs. I can't vouch for the absolute correctness of [this code](http://clam-project.org/clam/trunk/ipyclam/shibokenunwrap.cxx), but it appears to do what you want.

For PyQt, [the same comp.lib.qt.pyside thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.pyside/3819) links to an example of [unwrapping SIP objects](http://clam-project.org/clam/trunk/ipyclam/sipunwrap.cxx) which is again exactly what you need.

Comment: Could you summarize the contents of the link?  They look right, but links rot which reduces the long-term usefulness of this answer.

Comment: This is not a meaningful response much less an answer.