# How to add python plots into QT (c++) widget?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I want to add into my QT project a plot functionality. Since it is much simplier to create a plot in Python (Matplotlib, bokeh, etc.) I've decided to save some time. How to make QT(c++) and python understand each other?

Comment: Does [PythonQwt](https://pypi.org/project/PythonQwt/) solve your problem?

Comment: I need to use it from Qt (C++), not from python

Comment: To be clear, you want to access python libraries from C++? Or do you want to make a plot in python and embed it in a C++ Widget?

Comment: If it's the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678982/embedding-a-matplotlib-chart-into-qt-c-application. It certainly doesn't seem to be a simple problem.

Comment: Yes, I want somehow access a python libraries from C++. If it is possible